# Select element without tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have HTML structured like that:

```
<div class="in-featuredlisting">
    <h3 class="black">
        <a href="">title</a>
    </h3>
    <p class="sub-text in-newslisting">Posted on 15 March 2018</p>  
    lorem ipsum, bla, bla, bla   
</div>
```

If there is any way to capture.

> lorem ipsum, bla, bla, bla

part without "touching" or changing anything else `.in-featuredlisting`?

I tried `.in-featuredlisting p +` but this one doesn't work, because we don't have copy wrapped in element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Use `.contents()` along with `.text()` to get all text inside div.

2.At the same time neglect it's children elements text using `.not()` and `.children()`

3.use `$.trim()` to remove extra spaces.

```js
console.log($.trim($(".in-featuredlisting").contents().not($(".in-featuredlisting").children()).text()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="in-featuredlisting">
    <h3 class="black">
        <a href="">title</a>
    </h3>
    <p class="sub-text in-newslisting">Posted on 15 March 2018</p>  
   lorem ipsum, bla, bla, bla   
</div>
```

Comment: Answering duplicates fragments information across the sites. If the question is a duplicate then please don't answer it. People can follow the suggested duplicate link and the OP can accept the suggestion and close the question quicker.

Comment: @ChrisF  1. it's ask for 3 more votes to dupliacte a question when i do, meanwhile people post answers and my vote become useless. 2 the duplicate link have many solution and the best options is even not selected as an answer, that's why i added most suitable answer here along with the description too

Comment: I understand your concern, but it still ends up with information split across several questions. The suggested duplicate links are prominent enough for people to see and follow to find the information.

Comment: @ChrisF  i will take care of your suggestion in near future but my concern is also valuable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

1. First clone the parent element inside which the `text` with no tag is presented.
2. Then select all the children of this element.
3. Now, remove all the element from it which will remove the element that has HTML tags
4. Now, again go back to selected element so that you can reference that to get the text (which was not removed in step 3)
5. Finally, get the text from the parent element which you can further `trim` to remove the white spaces preceding and succeeding the text.

```js
var el = $(".in-featuredlisting");
var res = el.clone()    //step 1
        .children()     //step 2
        .remove()       //step 3
        .end()          //step 4
        .text();        //step 5
console.log(res.trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="in-featuredlisting">
    <h3 class="black">
        <a href="">title</a>
    </h3>
    <p class="sub-text in-newslisting">Posted on 15 March 2018</p>  
   lorem ipsum, bla, bla, bla   
</div>
```